How to add an arrow on a circular barplot using ggplot2
I want to add an arrow that represents the mean angle and the magnitude (like this figure https://i.sstatic.net/mZ8lB.png ). Far this way we got calculated the mean angle (=56.28) and the Rvalue (=0.6828)  using "circular" package. On the other hand a made the figures using "ggplot2", with the script below. Could anyone helpe putting this arrow?
Thanks in advance.
Data:
mes <- c("janeiro", "fevereiro", "marco", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro")
flor <- c(66.67, 93.33, 95.00, 93.33, 65.00, 20.00, NA, NA,  0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 40.00)
angulo <- c(0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330)
dados_canavalia <- data.frame (mes, angulo, flor)
dados_canavalia$mes<- factor(dados_canavalia$mes, ordered = TRUE, levels =c("janeiro","fevereiro", "marco", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro"))
str(dados_canavalia)  


Script:
plt_canavalia <- ggplot(dados_canavalia) +   # Your data name here
  # Make custom panel grid
  geom_hline(
    aes(yintercept = y), 
    data.frame(y = c(0,25,50,75,100)),#Your custom data range
    color = "lightgrey"
    ) +
  geom_col(
    aes(
      x = mes, # The x axis to reorder from minimum to maximum
      y = flor, # This axis represents the height of the bars in barplot.
      fill = flor # The represents the colour intensity of the barplot.
    ),
    position = "dodge2",
    show.legend = FALSE,
    alpha = .9
  )+
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = mes,
      y = 0,
      xend = mes,
      yend = 100 #The maximum values you want to extend the line.
    ),
    linetype = "dashed",
    color = "gray12"
  ) + 
  coord_polar()+  # Make it circular!
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 100),
    expand = c(0,0),
    breaks = c(0,50,100)
  ) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(               # New fill and legend title for number of tracks per region
    "Porcentagem de indivíduos (%)",
    colours = c( "#F8D8D8","#F8A8A8","#F07070","#E85830"),
    limits= c(0,100),
    breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 25)
  ) +
  # Make the guide for the fill discrete
  guides(
    fill = guide_colorsteps(
      barwidth = 35, barheight = 1, title.position = "top", title.hjust = .5
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    # Remove axis ticks and text
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    # Use gray text for the region names
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "gray12", size = 30), #TAMANHO das letras dos meses
    # Move the legend to the bottom
    legend.position = "bottom"
  )+
  # Add labels
  labs(
    title = "\nCanavalia rosea",
    sep = "\n") +
  # Customize general theme
  theme(
    text = element_text(color = "gray12", family = "Arial"), # Set default color and font family for the text
    plot.title = element_text(face = "italic", size = 35 , hjust = 0.04),   # Customize the text in the title, subtitle, and caption
    legend.text = element_text(size = 27),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 24),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),  # Make the background white and remove extra grid lines
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Jan","Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"))
  
 



This layer should do it.
We can use annotate to add a one-off geom that is unrelated to the global source data frame (or any other). We convert the x values here since yours are based on months. Your Fev is the 2nd axis step, but is associated with angle 60, so we can divide our angle by 30 and add 1 to get the right axis step. Then angle 0 would be aligned to Jan 1, and angle 56.28 would be most of the way through Fev, almost to Mar.
 annotate("segment", x = 56.28/30 + 1, xend = 56.28/30 + 1,
           y = 0, yend = 68.28, 
           linewidth = 1, 
           arrow = arrow(angle = 20, type = "closed", length = unit(0.5, "line"))) +



Thank you very much. I noticed that still the arrow didnt get in the right place, to solve the problem I added 30 to the mean angle value:
"annotate("segment", x = (56.28+30)/30, xend = (56.28+30)/30,
y = 0, yend = 68.28,
linewidth = 1,
arrow = arrow(angle = 20, type = "closed", length = unit(0.5, "line")))   "
Your advice was extremely helpfull, thanks!
